# something wrong with SpringbootTest MockBean error

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = JeecgSystemApplication.class)
public class SampleTest {
    
    @MockBean
    private CodeGenerateDbConfig initCodeGenerateDbConfig;

}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class CodeGenerateDbConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public CodeGenerateDbConfig initCodeGenerateDbConfig() {
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(url)){
            CodegenDatasourceConfig.initDbConfig(driverClassName,url, username, password);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

the error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register mock bean org.jeecg.config.init.CodeGenerateDbConfig expected a single matching bean to replace but found [codeGenerateDbConfig, initCodeGenerateDbConfig]
```

Comment: that is not an error, it's some missing configuration. Your mock doesn't know which bean of that type you want mocked. It's been a while since I used that type of mocking, but my guess using a Qualifier would be able to help out here

Comment: The error describes the problem properly. Your test class can not find a unique bean according to your configuration, because both `initCodeGenerateDbConfig` and `CodeGenerateDbConfig` are the same beans. I think using `@Qualifier` will solve the problem.

Comment: Your `@Configuration` is a `CodeGenerateDbConfig` then you misuse/abuse an `@Bean` method to do some initialization which also returns a `CodeGenerateDbConfig`. Ditch that `@Bean` method and put the code in an `@PostConstruct` method.

Answer (score 1):

MockBean does not seem to be supported , so it must be specified manually

Manually specifying the type to inject starts normally.

```
@MockBean(classes = {CodeGenerateDbConfig .class})
```

Would you like to manually specify the type to inject?